# Trouble installing mysql-python

Tags: python, mysql, macos, osx-lion

I downloaded [`MySQL-python-1.2.3.tar.gz`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/mysql-python/1.2.3/), unzipped and untarred it, and ran `sudo python setup.py build`.  I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "/Users/me/sources/MySQL-python-1.2.3/setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
    libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
  File "/Users/me/sources/MySQL-python-1.2.3/setup_posix.py", line 24, in mysql_config
    raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
```

A search for mysql_config on my computer with `find / -name mysql_config` found no matches.  I'm Using Mac OS X 10.7.2, with Python 2.7.1 installed.

Comment: Do you have MySQL installed on your machine? Looks like what you're trying to install is just a MySQL API for Python.

Comment: Ah, makes sense.  I thought mysql-python would install python too.  Can you post what you said as an answer so I can mark it right?

Comment: I'd really recommend using `easy_install` for installing Python modules. Ships with OS X and you can simply use `easy_install MySQL-python`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like what you're trying to install is just a MySQL API for Python. You should [install](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/macosx-installation.html) MySQL on your system first and then this library.